# Read complex JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json like :

```
var data = [
   {
      "country":"Andorra",
      "code":"AD",
      "state":[
         {
            "state_code":"AD1",
            "state_description":"aaAndorra1"
         },
         {
            "state_code":"AD2",
            "state_description":"aaAndorra2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I would like to loop though the state property and get the state_code value

This is how I'm doing it :

```
for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if(data[key].state.state_code === "AD1"){
                console.log(data[key].state.state_description);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting undefined.

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: Note, [it's not generally recommended to use `for..in` loops with Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Comment: Can someone stick with my code please and add what is necessary to access the state_code property? I don't want a new solution but a fix for mine.Thanks

Comment: just put it in the dev console (f12 on chrome) with "debugger;" line before it. by debugging it you will understand the problem in seconds.

Comment: @oussamakamal The short answer is: "You'll need a 2nd loop – `data[key1].state[key2].state_code`, etc." Beyond that, the answers being given are suggesting fixes, they're just also suggesting better practices.

Answer (score 1):

Try to iterate from the outer object and print it,

```
data.forEach(function(country){ //For the countries
  country.state.forEach(state){ //For the states
    console.log(state.state_code,state.state_description);
  });
});
```

As a side note, You should not use `for-in` loop while iterating over an array. Since it will iterate over all the `enumerable` properties of an object throughout the `prototypes`. I saw you using `.hasOwnProperty()`, that would help avoid such situations, but in our case, using for-in loop is unnecessary.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hp6vj1sk/)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].state.length; j++) {
        if(data[i].state[j].state_code === "AD1"){
            console.log(data[i].state[j].state_description)
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array with every state_code:

```
var result = data.reduce(function(ar, d) {
    // iterate over the state array of each item
    d.state.forEach(function(s){
      // push the state_code property to our resulting array
      // you could add a condition such as 
      // if(s.state_code === "AD1") ar.push(s.state_code)
      ar.push(s.state_code)
    });
    return ar;
}, [])
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxLgamdr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
data.forEach(function(obj){
  
 var states = obj.state;
 if(Array.isArray(states)){
   
   states.forEach(function(state){
     if(state.state_code === "AD1"){
      console.log(state.state_description);
     }
   });
 } else {
   if(states.state_code === "AD1"){
      console.log(states.state_description);
   }
 }
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for...in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an **object**

For iterating `Arrays` use [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop or [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].state.length; j++) {
        if (data[i].state[j].state_code === "AD1") {
            console.log(data[i].state[j].state_description);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declare data variable is an array of object. Where each object contains an array of state in it. Hence, if you want to iterate into deep, loop should be something like this (it is working fine, i have tested).

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j <= data[i].state.length; j++){
            alert("The code is ::" + data[i].state[j].state_code);
        }
    }
```